# If I made custom sys call and queue in my kernel, is it thread safe?

Tags: linux, kernel, system-calls

In Linux-4.4 kernel, Let's suppose there is my own system call and queue. 
I write linux-4.4/kernel/my_queue.c file which contains definition of int array as global variable and push, pop function as interface of queue.

And then, Is it thread-safe?

Sorry for my bad english.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Linux kernel **doesn't serialize system calls** automatically. It is possible for one system call to be called *in parallel* with itself (but from a different thread).

If a system call implementation accesses to a global variable, you need to synchronize this access for make things work properly.